# Group_concat() cuts some rows

Tags: mysql, group-concat

My Query is as follows:

```
select id, value from X where sig_id=1;
```

--> fetches nearly 1000 rows;

But when I use,

```
select id,
round(SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(if(sig_id =1, value,0) order by sig_value desc),',',1),2) 
from X;
```

--> fetches only 1 row;

```
I also get a warning,

Row 74 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Easy. Don't use GROUP_CONCAT. To my way of thinking, there is (almost) no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, in your below query you are doing a `GROUP_CONCAT()` without any `GROUP BY` and so the grouping is done on entire resultset as a single group. Thus, resulting in only one records.

```
select id,
round(SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(if(sig_id =1, value,0) order by sig_value desc),',',1),2) 
from X;
```

You may actually want to use `GROUP BY` on some column say `id` column to get multiple grouping results.

Comment: Yes Thanks. My bad.. I missed it .

Comment: For some reason I was not able to accept my answer until now.. Jus now was able to do it. did it :)